# Serialize model objects into a JSON dict using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

So if I have the following model class in Django:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

and my goal is to serialize it into the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "is_active": true,
    "contact": {
        "address1": "Bloggs House"
        "address2": "1 Bloggs Lane",
        "city": "Bloggs Town",
        "county": "Bloggs Town",
        "zip": "BL0 GG5",
        "country": "UK"
    }
}
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work and I'm pretty sure that's not how the serializers.ListField is meant to work (I think it's meant to be for a list of the same thing):

```
class MailChimpListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    contact = serializers.DictField(
        address1=serializers.CharField(source='address_line1'),
        address2=serializers.CharField(source='address_line2'),
        city=serializers.CharField(source='town'),
        state=serializers.CharField(source='town', read_only=True),
        zip=serializers.CharField(source='post_code'),
        country=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    )

    permission_reminder = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    campaign_defaults = serializers.DictField(
        from_name=serializers.CharField(source='name'),
        from_email=serializers.CharField(source='primary_contact_email'),
        subject=serializers.CharField(),
        language=serializers.CharField()
    )

    email_type_option = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    fields = ('name', 'contact', 'permission_reminder',
              'campaign_defaults', 'email_type_option')
```

How do I create the contact JSON list with the address etc in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a [`DictField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield) not a `ListField`, the key `contact` in your desired JSON output is an object (dict in Python), not a list:

```
contact = serializers.DictField(
            address1=serializers.CharField(source='address_line1'),
            address2=serializers.CharField(source='address_line2'),
            ...
)
```

Here's another way that is more manual:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_contact(self, obj):
        return dict(
            address1=obj.address1, # As long as the fields are auto serializable to JSON
            some_field=SomeSerializer(obj.some_field).data,
        )
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `line 1495, in __init__
    super(DictField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'city'`

Comment: @Cephlin only `city`? the other fields had no problem? I'll try this out in a bit. In the meantime, try the other manual method I added.

Comment: they all hit the same exception when I start commenting them out one by one. Ahh the SerializerMethodField, I didn't think of doing it that way.

Comment: @Cephlin Yeah that should work too, until I can see why `DictField` isn't working for us.

Comment: I got it working with the `SerializerMethodField`, thank you.